# Using a variable Wild Card parameter to SELECT from several FIELDS with OR

Tags: sql, select, wildcard

I am trying to create a more versatile search capability for my website's repair videos. I am using this to break the search field POST into wild card words.

```
$words = EXPLODE(" ",$search_term);
FOR($i=0;$i<count($words);$i++){$query_string .= "videos.Title LIKE '%".$words[$i]."%' AND ";}
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE $query_string;
```

This works for one FIELD "videos.Title".
I would like to search more fields in the data for results. It works with one word but two or more words causes a problem...

I was trying this:

```
SELECT * FROM videos
WHERE Title LIKE $query_string
OR Description LIKE $query_string
OR PartNumber LIKE $query_string
OR KeyWords LIKE $query_string
OR Brand LIKE $query_string
OR Item LIKE $query_string
OR Models LIKE $query_string;
```

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM videos
WHERE Title LIKE $query_string
OR (Description LIKE $query_string)
OR (PartNumber LIKE $query_string);
```

-Did not work-

I also tried

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE '$query_string' IN (Title, Description, PartNumber)
```

-Did not work-

Any Ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: What do you mean by *did not work*?

Comment: Is it `PHP`? Something else?

Comment: yes it is PHP. One word works fine with all SELECT statement but I get no results when searching for more than one word with the expanded SELECT statements. More than one word works fine when using the first videos.Title SELECT statement.